# TypeError: message.author is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

For this piece of code, I aim for the author of the message that sent the ban command to be checked for whether they have the permissions necessary to ban the member, instead of instantly being allowed to, however I am unsure of what the const mod should be equivalent to to do so. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: "This command ban a member!",
    execute(message, args) {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        const mod = message.author();
        
        if (mod.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
            if (target) {
                const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
                memberTarget.ban();
                message.channel.send("User has been banned");
                
            }
            
            
        } else if (mod.hasPermission(!'BAN_MEMBERS')) {
            message.channel.send(`You couldn't ban that member either because they don't exist or because you dont have the required roles!`);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you get when you run `typeof message.author`?

Comment: When I use typeof message.author in my code or just message.author?

Comment: `typeof` will tell you what kind of data is in there if any.

Comment: `typeof message.author` will return `'object'`, not `'function'` because it's a property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says, [`Message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) is not a *function*. It is a *property*. You access it without the brackets

```js
const mod = message.author
```

Another problem you may get is you can't get permissions. You will need [`Message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) for that

```js
const mod = message.member
```

Comment: Hi, I seem to get the error considering later on in the code that 
TypeError: mod.hasPermission is not a function

Comment: I edited that with the other problem. However, if this solved your original problem, you can upvote, and when possible, accept the answer. For another question you will have to make a separate question

Comment: Yeah thanks so much! I was able to get to the bottom of it